# JSON request payload with collection navigation properties?

Tags: json, collections, properties, navigation, odata

Does the OData JSON protocol (any version) support a request payload that contains a single entity (i.e. not batched) which contains a navigation property, where the navigation property contains a set of deferred entries?

I've studied the spec, and it looks like this is not defined, or at least not defined for versions 2 and 3...

> **2.2.6.3.2 Entity Set (as a JSON Array)**
>   "The syntax of the JSON representation of a collection of entities is defined by the grammar
>   listed in this section. The grammar rule "entitySetInJson" defines the
>   version 1.0 JSON representation of a collection of entities that may
>   be used in both request and response payloads. The grammar rule
>   "entitySetInJson2" defines the version 2.0 and the version 3.0 JSON
>   representation of a collection of entities for response payloads only.
>   There is no change between the version 1.0 and the version 2.0 or
>   version 3.0 formats for use in request payloads that are defined by
>   this specification."

and

> **2.2.6.3.10 Links**
>   The syntax of the JSON representation of a collection of links is
>   defined by the grammar listed in this section. The grammar rule
>   "linkCollJson" defines the version 1.0 JSON representation of a
>   collection of links that can be used in both request and response
>   payloads. The grammar rule "linkCollJson2" defines the version 2.0 and
>   version 3.0 JSON representation of a collection of links for response
>   payloads only. This specification does not define a version 2.0 or a
>   version 3.0 JSON representation of a collection of links for use in
>   request payloads.

To me this says that in OData V1 it is possible to upload an object with URI values ascribed to its collection navigation properties, and that in V2 and V3 that is not possible. The ATOM serialization does not call out this distinction.

Is my understanding correct, or have I missed something. And can anyone provide me some background on the reason for the changes described above?

Many thanks in advance.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The spec is a bit unclear at this point but what it means when it says that 2.0 and 3.0 versions are not specified for request payloads, it means that in request payloads you should use the 1.0 version of the payload since no new versions are defined.
It is possible to insert a new entity with expanded navigation property which contains a collection of entities. For example you can insert a new Category along with 5 Products which belong to that category.
The deferred links are also possible and what that does is to bind the new entity to the existing entities referenced by those links.
Note though, that WCF Data Services currently only supports this on inserts (POST), it doesn't support it on updates (PUT/MERGE/...).

Comment: Thanks Vitek. We are not using WCF but instead are using the MSFT OData Library within our own MVC framework. This allows us to support PUT/MERGE (& PATCH) as well. I did notice that if I select ODataVersion.V1 that the library parses a body containing a collection navigation property and for V2|V3 it fails. IOW the functionality appears to have been dropped from OData. I've been hesitant to take a dependency on the V1 behavior for two reasons. First, it seems that it would lose support of client frameworks over time and second, we may need to use V2|V3 features in a concurrent request.

Comment: I don't know which version of the library you use (try the latest CTP from October please). In any case there were changes to how the expanded navigation properties are read in request payloads especially in JSON (to align with the current WCF DS behavior). In any case it would be interesting to see what payload works in V1 and doesn't work in V2/V3.

Comment: We are using the Feb 11 2011 'alpha' version: http://odata.codeplex.com/releases/view/60787

This was an update to the Oct 27 2010 version (which we started with).

Comment: Is there a more recent version? If we don't provide version 1 for the data service version header the serializer will throw the following: "A node of type 'StartArray' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of a feed with a feed wrapper object. A 'StartObject' node was expected."

Comment: Please try the latest CTP: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx
It might be fixed there, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Vitek, looks like that did the trick. Is the source for the OData library going to be released again? We had a workaround for lack of timespan deserialization in JSON, and it looks like that's still not implemented (which is a shame since it's a one-liner).

Comment: It will be released after we release the RTM. The RTM will support the Edm.Time as well, I'm actually surprised that didn't make it into the CTP, oh well :-).

Comment: Thanks again. 

BTW, Edm.Time is incorrectly described in the examples on this page: [link](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/overview#AbstractTypeSystem)

The examples show a format based on the time portion of Edm.DateTime but the spec (referenced in the same row) and the implementation say otherwise.